# Is there any chance of fixing it?

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]I am new to arduino and robotic stuffs and I thought it would be a good idea to test circuits on my breadboard using arduino's R3 5V pin as power supply. The accident happened when I short circuited the things on the breadboard and after a while arduino gave off a nasty smell. The only part overheated on arduino was the left side of the micro-controller. After that I cant upload nor run code on arduino.

After I explained you my situation, can you imagine a potential problem?(e.g I mean is it a voltage regultor problem, a micro-controller faillure, both of them, or something else?)

Can I fix it?

(#1 - I know arduino boards are cheap. I just want to know if I can do anything        with that.

#2 - No comments about  the accident accepted.)

Thank's in advance.

Regarding the image, my vendor claims the arduino to be an exact copy of "open-source" arduino R3

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54018/discussion-on-question-by-nick-is-there-any-chance-of-fixing-it).

Answer (score 3):

> Can I fix it?

If your power supply still works, there's a decent chance you can repair the board by replacing its microcontroller which is conveniently socketed.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I fix it?

it depends on your skills and the nature of the problem and how far you are willing to go to fix it.

I would first try to rule out a supply problem - very rarely a mcu will burn to the extent of giving off smells / overheat. So unplug the mcu and use a multimeter to measure its Vcc vs. GND pin voltage, test trace continuity, etc.

after that, plug in a new / known good chip and see if you could upload code to it.